# Installing ubuntu on windows 8.1

Tags: usb

Hi I have downloaded the 64 bit off ubuntu ,put it on a USB stick but when I try to boot it up in windows 8.1 it does not give me the option of booting it , help please

Comment: Your USB flash drive maybe isn't bootable. Create it bootable using [UUI Software](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). then do @jnuk's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot from the USB stick *instead* of Windows.
You will have to select the boot device during POST (just after you turn on the PC) by pressing a specific button. (It should say which one on the display).

---

As described in the comments, you need create an UEFI bootable USB stick by using f.e. [this tool](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

Comment: I don't think it does , does not give me the option of pressing f8 like in previous windows 7 ,

Comment: Even before that. Try pressing the common keys like F11, F10, F9... right after you press the power button.

Comment: No that doesn't work either

Comment: Can you enter BIOS setup? It's usually DEL, F1, F12, but you may need to try some other keys

Comment: There is no bios set up on windows 8.1 it's been changed to UEFI but there is no option to boot from USB in it

Comment: Glad you got it to work! Can you then please mark my answer as correct, so others who have the same problem will find the answer more easily? Thank you.